# What does putting a parameter in @Entity() do?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

```
@Entity('user')
export class UserEntity {  
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid') id: string;  
    @Column({ 
        type: 'varchar', 
        nullable: false, 
        unique: true 
    }) 
    username: string;
    @Column({ 
        type: 'varchar', 
        nullable: false 
    }) 
    password: string;  
}
```

What purpose does the 'user' in @Entity() have? In the controller, we put parameters inside the @Get() or similar methods to specify route...but no such thing happens in the Entity file.

This is where I got the code from: https://www.codemag.com/Article/2001081/Nest.js-Step-by-Step-Part-3-Users-and-Authentication

Answer (score 0):

This parameter overrides the default table name used for that entity. In your case the table would be called `"user"`. If you didn't pass this parameter the table name would have been `"userEntity"` or `"user_entity"`, I'm not quite sure.